# Web app unable to access private s3 file even though IAM policy grants access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, policy, amazon-iam

I am using CarrierWaveDirect to upload a high resolution images to s3.  I then use that image to process multiple versions which are made public through Cloudfront urls.

The uploaded high res files need to remain private to anonymous users, but the web application needs to access the private file in order to do the processing for other versions.

I am currently setting all uploaded files to private in the CarrierWave initializer via

config.fog_public  = false

I have an IAM policy for the web application that allows full admin access.  I also have set the ACCESSKEY AND SECRETKEY in the app for that IAM user. Given these two criteria, I would think that the web app could access the private file and continue with processing, but it is denied access to the private file.

*When I log into the user account associated with the web app, I am able to access the private file because a token is added on to the URL.

I can't figure out why the app cannot access the private file given the ACCESSKEY AND SECRRETKEY

Comment: What is the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: @messages={:image=>["could not download file: 403 Forbidden"]}>

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I can view the private file from within the AWS console when logged in as the user corresponding with the web app credentials

Comment: I think my answer may lie here with adding query parameters for authenticating the request http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

Comment: This gist is on the right track, but is out of date with the current AWS query requirements https://gist.github.com/iwasrobbed/1032395

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time getting to your problem. I am quite certain your question is not

> unable to access private s3 file even though IAM policy grants access

but rather

> how to handcraft a presigned URL for GETting a private file on S3

The gist shows you're trying to create the presigned URL for GET yourself. While this is perfectly fine, it's also **very error-prone.**

Please verify that what you're trying to do is working at all, using the AWS SDK for Ruby (I only post code known to work with version 1 here but if you aren't held back by legacy code, start with version 2):

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets["your-bucket-name"]
obj = bucket.objects["your-object-path"]
obj.url_for(:read, expires: 10*60) # generate a URL that expires in 10 minutes
```

See the docs for [`AWS::S3::S3Object#url_for`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method) and [`Aws::S3::Object#presigned_url`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#presigned_url-instance_method) for details.

You may need to read up on passing args to `AWS::S3.new` [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3.html) (for credentials, regions and so).

I'd advise you take the following steps:

1. Make it work locally using the `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key`
2. Make it work in your worker
3. If it works, you can compare the query string the SDK returned with the one you handcrafted yourself. Maybe you can spot an error.

**But in any case, I suggest you use higher-level SDKs to do things like that for you.**

If this doesn't get you anywhere, please post a comment with your new findings.

Comment: I got things working with the signed URL as you mentioned. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011035/unable-to-reproduce-aws-signature-from-example-using-hmac-sha256